# R Iterate DataFrame Columns from List, Error: undefined columns selected

Tags: r, dataframe

I am placing column names in a list and then want to select those columns from Data Frame. I am using following code

```
features <- list(c("Weeks"), c("Weeks","Age"))
X = train_linear[,as.character(features[1])] # working fine

X = train_linear[,as.character(features[2])]
```

Last line is giving following error.

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(train_linear, , as.character(features[2])): undefined columns selected
Traceback:

1. train_linear[, as.character(features[2])]
2. `[.data.frame`(train_linear, , as.character(features[2]))
3. stop("undefined columns selected")
```

It took lot of time but I found nothing about this. Instead of list if I do this,

```
X = train_linear[,c("Weeks","Age")]
```

Then it is working perfectly. But I need to create few columns combinations and list is best option for me in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to `unlist` if it is `[` or directly get the `list` element with `[[`

```
train_linear[, features[[2]]]
```

There is no need to use `as.character` as it is already a string.

The issue is with the coersion in `as.character`.  When there is a single element in a `list`

```
features[1]
#[[1]]  #  // still a list with one element
#[1] "Weeks"

as.character(features[1]) # // coerces to vector as it calls as.vector
#[1] "Weeks"
as.character(features[2]) # // note the added double quotes
#[1] "c(\"Weeks\", \"Age\")"
```

and now it is a single string instead of two elements because it is concatenated by calling `paste`

```
length(as.character(features[2]))
#[1] 1
```

whereas if we use `[[`, it returns a `vector`

```
features[[2]]
#[1] "Weeks" "Age"  

features[[1]]
#[1] "Weeks"

is.vector(features[[2]])
#[1] TRUE


is.list(features[2])
#[1] TRUE
is.list(features[[2]])
#[1] FALSE
```

---

Regarding the comment about why selecting a single column return a `vector`, it is related to the feature of `data.frame` where the `?Extract` is by default `drop = TRUE`.

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]

i.e. based on the usage from the help page of Extract, when there is a single column, row, it coerces to a vector.  If we need to use `,` to separate the row, column index, then we need to specify `drop = FALSE` as well or otherwise simply specify the column index or names without a comma

```
train_linear[, features[[1]], drop = FALSE]
```

Or

```
train_linear[features[[1]]]
```

Comment: Btw, selecting a single column is not giving a dataframe. Multiple columns selection is returning a dataframe.

Comment: Got it. But now instead of indexing features[[1]], I am looping over "features" variable and doing it as "X = train_linear[,feature]" So, I have to put condition if length is 1 then use drop=FALSE otherwise fine.

Comment: Looping over feature column was too easy, I should have done that earlier.

Comment: @HammadHassan You can always add `drop = FALSE` or without the `,` instead of a if/else condition.  I would avoid creating more conditions in the code unless it is absolutely necessary